# find Base for sub space

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

We were asked in the exam to find base for $W$ , such that $W$ is the the matrices $B$ of the form $M_{2 \times 2 } (\mathbb{R})$ such that $A B = B A$

Were $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 2\\ 3 && 4 \end{bmatrix}$

I found that $ W= span (\begin{bmatrix} 0 && \frac{2}{3}\\ 1 && 1 \end{bmatrix})$

Is my solution correct ??!

Comment: Can you explain how you got to your solution?

Comment: i took $B = \begin{bmatrix} a && b\\ c && d \end{bmatrix}$, found out what $AB$ is equal and what $B A$ equals, and then got a linear system equations which are spanned by $ (0,2/3,1,1)$ @Useless

Comment: You should find that $W$ is a two-dimensional space (since $A$ has 2 distinct eigenvalues)

Comment: One convenient base is $\{I,A\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your solution is not correct. The space $W$ is spanned by all the matrices of the form 
$$B=\begin{bmatrix}
    a       & b \\
    3b/2    & a+3b/2
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $a,b$ are any real number. In particular, the matrix you got is obtained for $a=0$ and $b=2/3$; the identity matrix, that commutes with any other matrix, so it must be in $W$, is obtained for $a=1$ and $b=0$; and the matrix $A$, which obviously commutes with itself, is obtained for $a=1$ and $b=2$. If you prefer, you can say that the 2-dimensional space $W$ is spanned by the matrices 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    1       & 0 \\
    0    & 1
\end{bmatrix}\quad \text{and}\qquad \begin{bmatrix}
    0       & 1 \\
    3/2    & 3/2
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
You can verify the result in [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1,2%7D,%7B3,4%7D%7D*%7B%7Ba,b%7D,%7B3b%2F2,a%2B3b%2F2%7D%7D%3D%3D%7B%7Ba,b%7D,%7B3b%2F2,a%2B3b%2F2%7D%7D*%7B%7B1,2%7D,%7B3,4%7D%7D).

Comment: Notably, your choice of basis is $\{I,(A - I)/2\}$